# Implementing Gridview paging in asp.net 2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

i am using asp.net 2008 and i have implemented the in-build Gridview Paging.But it didn't work.then how can i implement Gridview Paging?i am using sql server 2005.

Comment: what datasource are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the GridView.AllowPaging property to true. Ensure that your data source supports the paging.